# Why doesn't my Perl pipe to zcat die if the file is not there?

Tags: perl, pipe, zcat

If my gz file does not exist, why doesn't it DIE?

```
$ cat test.pl    
open(FILE, "zcat dummy.gz |") or die "DIE";

$ ./test.pl    
zcat: dummy.gz: No such file or directory
```

If I read a file normally, it works as expected:

```
$ cat test2.pl    
open(FILE, "dummy.gz") or die "DIE";

$ ./test2.pl    
DIE at ./test.pl line 2.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `open` succeeds (as it successfully runs zcat), you won't get `zcat`'s exit code until you close the file descriptor though.

You might want to check if the file exists and is readable before you start though, eg.

```
die "unable to read file" unless (-f "dummy.gz" and -r "dummy.gz")
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider using `PerlIO::gzip`, eg.

```
use PerlIO::gzip;
open(FILE, '<:gzip', 'dummy.gz') or die $!;
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second example, the **file opened by perl** does not exist, so it will die.

In your first example, the **command called by perl** executes (with any result), so there is no reason to die.